# JSON not getting the collection of data in VBA Excel 2010

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have started creating an excel for stock watch in 2010 and havent been able to parse properly.

Instead of getting the columns with [symbol] and prices i only get first four tags and nothing inside data.

This is the code:

```
Sub getJSON()
Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/foSecStockWatch.json"
MyRequest.Send
MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText

Dim jsonText As String
Dim jsonObj As Dictionary
Dim jsonRows As Collection
Dim jsonRow As Collection
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim startColumn As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("A1") = MyRequest.ResponseText
MsgBox ws.Range("A1").Value

jsonText = ws.Range("A1").Value
'jsonText = MyRequest.ResponseText
'Parse it
Set jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonText)

'Get the rows collection
'Error here'
Set jsonRows = jsonObj("symbol")

'Set the starting row where to put the values
currentRow = 1

'First column where to put the values
startColumn = 2 'B

'Loop through all the values received
For Each jsonRow In jsonRows
    'Now loop through all the items in this row
    For i = 1 To jsonRow.Count
        ws.Cells(currentRow, startColumn + i - 1).Value = jsonRow(i)
    Next i

    'Increment the row to the next one
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Next jsonRow
End Sub
```

Also as this is excel 2010 and doing it as a newbie let me know if this is the correct way to parse json as i am going to create multiple excels with different urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inspect the JSON structure and write your code accordingly. The `[]` means collection which you can `For Each` over the items of. The `{}` means dictionary which you can loop over the keys of. The blue and green squares (in the image of your JSON below) are string literals (key,value pairs).

You initially get back a dictionary containing a mixture of key, value pairs (e.g. `noChg`, `5`); with one key, `data`, being to a collection of inner dictionaries.

[image]

`jsonObj("symbol")` if you had parsed with `ParseJson` and following syntax:

```
Set jsonObj = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText) '<== dictionary
```

would have failed as `symbol` is a key in the inner dictionaries, within the collection `data`, and not directly accessible from the initial top level JSON dictionary.

Instead, you need to loop the initial dictionary and write out the key, value pairs and test if the key is `data`. If the key is `data`, you instead need to loop the items in the collection (each being a dictionary), and loop the keys of those dictionaries.

A little thought as to how you increment row and column counters, and testing for the first time the inner dictionary keys are looped, to get the headers only once, will result in a tidy write out of data to sheet.

**NOTE:** I am using [JSONConverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to parse the JSON. After adding this to the project, I also go to VBE > Tools > References and add a reference to ***Microsoft Scripting Runtime***.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim json As Object, item As Object, key As Variant, key2 As Variant, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/foSecStockWatch.json", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText) '<== dictionary
    End With

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, headerRow As Long
    For Each key In json '<== Loop initial dictionary
        r = r + 1          
        If key = "data" Then '<==collection of dictionaries
            For Each item In json("data")
                headerRow = headerRow + 1
                c = 1
                For Each key2 In item '<== individual dictionary
                    If headerRow = 1 Then '<==  test to write out headers of symbols info only once
                        ws.Cells(r, c) = key2
                        ws.Cells(r + 1, c) = item(key2)
                    Else
                        ws.Cells(r + 1, c) = item(key2)
                    End If
                    c = c + 1
                Next
                r = r + 1
            Next
        Else  'string literal key, value pairs 
            ws.Cells(r, 1) = key: ws.Cells(r, 2) = json(key)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Sample of data in sheet:**

[image]

Comment: I am not able to run above code.Getting variable not defined on method Public Sub Getinfo().
Is there any way to work around my code instead of a new one.Like what should i change in my code.
As parsing Symbol doesnt work so how should i get data and then 0 and Symbol and set that collection to jsonrows from jsonobj

Comment: Please check above comment.Also JsonConverter is a new library right which i will have to import?

Comment: It is a new library link provided in answer above.  You might simply get away with changing one line to Set json = JSON.parse(.responseText)

Comment: Also, I would not expect a _variable not defined_ error on this line: Public Sub Getinfo().. That is just a signature with no variable declarations.

Comment: The main error in your code remains the same. You need to access jsonObj("data") to get the collection of dictionaries which you can loop over to access by key _symbol_ etc from each inner dictionary.

Comment: Got it.So i changed code like below:
    jsonText = ws.Range("A1").Value
    'Parse it
    Set jsonObj = json.parse(MyRequest.ResponseText)
    
    'Get the rows collection
    Set jsonRows = jsonObj("data")
    
    'Set the starting row where to put the values
    currentRow = 1

i am getting data which is a dictionary and i am getting type mismatch in next line ie. currentRow =1.Is that because dictionary cannot be traversed?

Comment: What json parser are you using please? Is there a link to it for download? And why is your assignment going from sheet to jsonText? Oh.... I see you are writing response to sheet and then reading back in.

Comment: Yes..i am using http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html.
"JSON.bas", "cJSONScript.cls" and "cStringBuilder.cls" imported to project.

Added a reference to the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library and to the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" library.

Comment: you literally just need to use the following bit of code in yours and swop json for jsonObj in my code and put initial value of c as 2 not 1. https://filebin.net/prh8cb9ogq8jdakp

Comment: Ok..so i tried using for each loop on dictionary to get data which is again a dictionary.
Also what is the use of adding request header at the start?
Is there any way to exclude the first three rows noChg,adv and dec and directly start with symbol in A1?

Comment: The request header is to mitigate being served cached results which can be a problem with very frequently changing data such as stock prices. If you only want what is in "data" then only process if key = "data". See the pastebin I linked to above.

Comment: Done...pheww..Thanks a lot...How do you know so much about json?
Did you frigging invent json?

Comment: No. But I always like to paste my JSON into a [JSON viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) and inspect its structure so I can structure my code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks..One more query..Do you know how to add referer to the request?
When i get data using the official website it sends a GET request and gives json data correctly but when i do it via the raw json string i get 405 error.Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can as it would be a security risk. You might be able to modify the approach shown here: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=9554

Comment: This is if you use xmlhttp.In my earlier approach i had winhttprequest.i will try to add over there.

Comment: I think with WinHTTP as well. It is to prevent spoofing of origin.

Comment: Hi @QHarr..i have got the referer with the request headers working and am getting data in the other excel..only problem is i am getting lot of white space before the actual json sting and i tried removing them via stringify but wasnt able too..can you help with this? it is on https://filebin.net/prh8cb9ogq8jdakp

Comment: Can this be removed used Trim$?

Comment: eg please?
is it a function of a parser ?

Comment: It’s a function which you pass a string e.g. x = Trim$(“         ABC”). Without the funny “ from being on mobile. It removed leading and trailing white space from strings.

Comment: ohh excel function..i thought with Vba or json..i tried with excel didnt work

Comment: It’s a Vba function. You put your string inside that you want to remove white space from. I assume that to be the not quite Json string.

Comment: https://filebin.net/prh8cb9ogq8jdakp..
getting syntax error compile error

Comment: I will have a look when using computer again. On mobile at moment.

Comment: ok..no problem..
I probably think that because request headers were added i am getting response headers as unreadable whitespaces..is that possible?